# How can I create a variable array name in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, variables

Array @p is a multiline array, e.g. $p[1] is the second line.

This code will explain what I want:

```
$size=@p;   # line number of array @p
for($i=0; $i<$size; $i++)
{ 
  @p{$i}= split(/ +/,$p[$i]);
}
```

I want the result should be like this:

```
@p0 = $p[0]          first line of array @p goes to array @p0;       
@p1 = $p[1]          second line of array @p goes to array @p1; 
...
...
```

and so on.

But above code does not work, how can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a bad idea to dynamically generate variable names.

I suggest the best solution here is to convert each line in your `@p` array to an array of fields.

Lets suppose you have a better name for `@p`, say `@lines`. Then you can write

```
my @lines = map [ split ], <$fh>;
```

to read in all the lines from the file handle `$fh` and split them on whitespace. The first field of the first line is then `$lines[0][0]`. The third field of the first line is `$lines[0][2]` etc.

Comment: I want to ask another question, I'm very appreciated your help...how can I change several same size arrays to one array like this:          my @A = (
  [0,0,1,0,1,0,0],
  [0,0,0,1,0,1,0],
  [1,0,0,1,0,0,0],
  [0,1,1,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,1,1],
  [0,1,0,0,1,0,1],
  [0,0,0,1,1,1,0]
  );

Answer (score 3):

First, the syntax `@p{$i}` accesses the entry with the key `$i` in a hash `%p`, and returns it in list context. I don't think you meant that. `use strict; use warnings;` to get warned about undeclared variables.

You can declare variables with `my`, e.g. `my @p;` or `my $size = @p`;

Creating variable names on the fly is possible, but a bad practice. The good thing is that we don't need to: Perl has *references*. A reference to an array allows us to nest arrays, e.g.

```
my @AoA = (
   [1, 2, 3],
   ["a", "b"],
);
say $AoA[0][1]; # 2
say $AoA[1][0]; # a
```

We can create an array reference by using brackets, e.g. `[ @array ]`, or via the reference operator `\`:

```
my @inner_array = (1 .. 3);
my @other_inner = ("a", "b");
my @AoA = (\@inner_array, \@other_array);
```

But careful: the array references still point to the same array as the original names, thus

```
push @other_inner, "c";
```

also updates the entry in `@AoA`:

```
say $AoA[1][2]; # c
```

Translated to your problem this means that you want:

```
my @pn;
for (@p) { 
  push @pn, [ split /[ ]+/ ];
}
```

There are many other ways to express this, e.g.

```
my @pn = map [ split /[ ]+/ ], @p;
```

or

```
my @pn;
for my $i ( 0 .. $#p ) {
  $pn[$i] = [ split /[ ]+/, $p[$i] ];
}
```

To learn more about references, read

- [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html),
- [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html), and
- [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html).

Comment: Most often, a programmer who writes `split /[ ]+/` actually wants `split ' '`